# How to delete Firestore document by passing it query?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this query:  `Query queryDelete = firestore.collection("images").whereEqualTo("imageUrl", model.getImageUrl());` and I want to pass it to `DocumentReference`, so that I can call something like this: `docRef.delete.addOnCompleteListener(...)`
Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to first get() your documents and then iterate over them and call delete() on them.

The following code is taken from the firestore docs page:

```
/** Delete a collection in batches to avoid out-of-memory errors.
 * Batch size may be tuned based on document size (atmost 1MB) and application requirements.
 */
void deleteCollection(CollectionReference collection, int batchSize) {
  try {
    // retrieve a small batch of documents to avoid out-of-memory errors
    ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> future = collection.limit(batchSize).get();
    int deleted = 0;
    // future.get() blocks on document retrieval
    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = future.get().getDocuments();
    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : documents) {
      document.getReference().delete();
      ++deleted;
    }
    if (deleted >= batchSize) {
      // retrieve and delete another batch
      deleteCollection(collection, batchSize);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Error deleting collection : " + e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data